# ActionController::RoutingError: No route matches [GET] "/signup

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, devise, routes

Running into an intermittent Ruby on rails routing issues with devise. The error occurs maybe one in ten times and we are not sure why.  Any help would be appreciated.

The error:

```
ActionController::RoutingError: No route matches [GET] "/signup/account"
... 27 non-project frames
1
File "/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-3.2.14/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb" line 21 in call
2
File "/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rollbar-0.10.14/lib/rollbar/middleware/rails/show_exceptions.rb" line 19 in call_with_rollbar
3
File "/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-3.2.14/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb" line 56 in call
4
File "/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/lograge-0.2.2/lib/lograge/rails_ext/rack/logger.rb" line 15 in call_app
5
File "/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.14/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb" line 16 in block in call
6
File "/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.14/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb" line 22 in tagged
7
File "/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.14/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb" line 16 in call
8
File "/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-3.2.14/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb" line 22 in call
9
File "/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/methodoverride.rb" line 21 in call
10
File "/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/runtime.rb" line 17 in call
11
File "/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.14/lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb" line 72 in call
12
File "/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/lock.rb" line 15 in call
13
File "/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-3.2.14/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb" line 63 in call
14
File "/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-ssl-1.3.3/lib/rack/ssl.rb" line 27 in call
15
File "/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-cache-1.2/lib/rack/cache/context.rb" line 136 in forward
16
File "/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-cache-1.2/lib/rack/cache/context.rb" line 245 in fetch
17
File "/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-cache-1.2/lib/rack/cache/context.rb" line 185 in lookup
18
File "/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-cache-1.2/lib/rack/cache/context.rb" line 66 in call!
19
File "/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-cache-1.2/lib/rack/cache/context.rb" line 51 in call
20
File "/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.14/lib/rails/engine.rb" line 484 in call
21
File "/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.14/lib/rails/application.rb" line 231 in call
22
File "/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/content_length.rb" line 14 in call
23
File "/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.14/lib/rails/rack/log_tailer.rb" line 17 in call
24
File "/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb" line 59 in service
25
File "/app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/httpserver.rb" line 138 in service
26
File "/app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/httpserver.rb" line 94 in run
27
File "/app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/server.rb" line 295 in block in start_thread
```

**My routes look like this:**

> ```
> cancel_user_registration GET  /signup/account/cancel(.:format) registrations#cancel
>
> user_registration      POST   /signup/account(.:format) registrations#create
>
> new_user_registration  GET    /signup/account/setup(.:format) registrations#new
>
> edit_user_registration GET    /signup/account/edit(.:format) registrations#edit
>                        PUT    /signup/account(.:format)                              registrations#update
>                        DELETE /signup/account(.:format)                              registrations#destroy
> ```

The routes file:

```
devise_for :users, :controllers => {:registrations => "registrations"}, :path => "signup", :path_names => {:sign_in => "login", :sign_out => "logout", :password => "secret", :confirmation => "verification", :unlock => "unblock", :registration => "account", :sign_up => "setup"}

    match "/users/account/setup" => "setup#index"

    #Setup the routes for the setup process:
    scope "/setup", controller: :setup, as: :setup do
        match "" =>  "setup#signup"
        match :signup
        match :account
        match :holidays
        match :organization
        match :add_employees
        match :roster_product_options
        match :account_holidays
        match :import_employees
        match :upgrade
        match :roster_setup_complete
    end
```

Comment: I certainly can's see the `GET "/signup/account"` in the `rake routes` you pasted. It looks as if you are actually missing that in your routes.rb. You have a ` POST   /signup/account` but not a  `GET   /signup/account` which is the one failing in your case.

Comment: I suppose its more a question of why in devise would i intermittently get this error. We have tried to do everything standard

Comment: Is it happening when there is an error on login?